# Can Oracle11g re-plan a statement in the middle of the query execution?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization

As known there are `IS_BIND_SENSITIVE` and `IS_BIND_AWARE` in **Oracle 11g**.

- `IS_BIND_AWARE` - to forced rebuild an execution plan of SQL-query, **before SQL-query started**
- `IS_BIND_SENSITIVE` - DBMS decides rebuild or not an execution plan of SQL-query, **before SQL-query started**

But Oracle11g rebuild an execution plan directly at runtime of SQL-query?

For example, Oracle is doing index-lookups for NLJ (Nested-Loop Join) for a long time and then in the middle of the query execution decides to cancel this strategy and do HJ (Hash Join). Can Oracle11g do this and if yes, with what settings?

Comment: Oracle does use a thing called "cardinality feedback", but I think this is only used for improving the *next* execution of the query

Comment: I believe this is one of the interesting changes in 12c : http://www.orafaq.com/node/2883